# Как связать профиль покупателя с профилем пользователя 1c bitrix?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, cms, оптимизация-сайтов

Добрый день!
На сайте есть профиль покупателя и профиль пользователя.
Когда делаешь обновление в профиле пользователя, изменяются данные и в профиле покупателя, но когда делаешь изменения в профиле покупателя, то данные в профиле пользователя не изменяются.
Как можно решить эту проблему?